# Где  произносят  так  же ?

Tags: фонетика

[image]   Вопрос - где  вырос  автор  этого  текста ?  Наш  форум  охватывает  всю  Россию  или,  возможно,  весь  бывший  СССР.  Где  произносят  так  же ?

Answer (score 1):

Увы, неграмотно сейчас произносят много где... Почитаешь интернет, вполне респектабельные сайты — там ошибка на ошибке, я уже не говорю о социальных сетях, где волосы шевелиться начинают, когда читаешь...
*А форум действительно охватывает весь бывший СССР и, насколько я знаю, даже страны дальнего зарубежья. Я, например, из Украины.*

Comment: Ну,  и  как  вы  произнесёте  это  слово ?  Пишут  неграмотно,  а  произносят  так  говорили  там,  где  выросли.  Правила  орфоэпии  тоже  есть,  но  обязательны  они,  думаю,  только  для  дикторов.

Answer (score 1):

Правила орфоэпии для устной речи так же важны, как правила орфографии для речи письменной.

Вот слово загрузчик: в нем на стыке корня и суффикса всртечаются зубный звук З и шипящий звук Ч. Зубный звук З - фрикативный, образуется при прохождении воздуха через узкую щель, передненебный звук Ч - аффриката (смычной+фрикативный). При их соединении смычная часть уходит, язык от зубов сдвигается к переднему небу - произносится мягкий передненебный фрикативный звук Щ. Это закон ПРАВИЛЬНОГО произношения, удобного для устной речи: во всех словах сочетание З/С+Ч произносится как Щ.

Теперь рассмотрим слово "загружчик". Я вообще не уверена, что перед нами фонетическое письмо. Возможно, автор считал, что написать по слуху "загрущик" как-то неприлично, но восстановил звуки на стыке морфем неправильно. Но если это действительно написано по слуху, то возможно,что вместо зубного З произносится передненебный Ж, который ближе по месту образования к передненебному Ч. Такое произношение, наверное, следует считать диалектным.

Comment: Вполне  может  быть.  Может  и  проверочное  слово  находил - загружать.  Может  и  клавишей  ошибся,  "ж"  и  "щ"  близко  друг  от  друга  расположены.  Но,  если  это  диалектное  произношение,  то  -  какое ?  Мне,  собственно,  это  хотелось  бы  узнать.  Или  подтвердить,  что  ошибка  с  диалектным   произношением   не  связана.

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос - где вырос автор этого текста ? Наш форум охватывает всю Россию или, возможно, весь бывший СССР. Где произносят так же ?

"Так" - это как?
Вы так много рисунков дали, что вопрос непонятен.
Если вы о слове "загружчик", то оно "фонетически" верно. Во всяком случае офроэпическая норма предписывает произносить С и З перед шипящими как Ш/Ж, что в сочетании с Ч дает Щ.
Ну а если вспомнить чередование Ж/З в "грузить"/"груженый", то орфография автора становится вполне понятной. Разумеется, это не делает её правильной.

Comment: Хоть  вопрос  и  точен,  но  вы   ведь   правильно   всё   поняли.  Слово  фонетически  вы  взяли  в  кавычки.  Значит  ли  это,  что  человек  произносит  правильно,  но,   помня,  что  не  всё   пишется,  как   произносится   вносит  в  письмо   соответствующие  коррективы ? Или  это  значит,  что  человек  в  самом  деле  так  произносит  или  слышит,  но  это  просто  разговорный  вариант,  а  не  диалектное  произношение ?

Comment: >Значит ли это, что человек произносит правильно, но, помня, что не всё пишется, как произносится вносит в письмо соответствующие коррективы?    
  
Не могу знать. Скорее всего люди пишут "на автомате". Почему они отступают от орфографического правила отнюдь не в пользу прямого фонетического можно только гадать. Видимо,  срабатывает какая-то ложная аналогия.
Вот вам пример. Слово "поручик" массово пишут "порутчик". Хотя ни орфографией, ни фонетикой такой вариант не предусмотрен. Срабатывает аналогия, например, с "прокатчик" или "заводчик".

Comment: Да,  есть  такое  явление.  Но  слово  "поручик"  в  активный  словарный  запас  не  входит  уже.  Может  поэтому  аналогия  и  срабатывает ?